# get friends of friend using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am making a query in which i want to get friends of friends but the problem is that if my friends are also friends it suggesting their ids too . Suppose user id is `1` and he has teo friends `2` and `3` and 2 has is friends with `4` and `3` and 3 is friends with `5` and `2` then its suggesting me `4,5` which it should but also suggesting `2,3` because they are friends and they both are also my friends which is wrong it should only suggest `4,5`

My query is

```
SELECT fr.friend_id 
FROM friend_list fl ,friend_list fr 
WHERE fl.login_id='27' 
AND fl.status='3' 
AND fl.friend_id=fr.login_id 
AND fr.status='3' 
AND fl.login_id!=fr.friend_id
```

Comment: Some sample data and table structure would definitely help to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add `WHERE NOT IN` predicate :

```
SELECT fr.friend_id 
FROM friend_list fl 
INNER JOIN friend_list fr  ON fl.friend_id = fr.login_id
                          AND fl.status = fr.status
WHERE fl.login_id = 27 AND fl.status = '3'
  AND fr.friend_id NOT IN(SELECT friend_id
                          FROM friend_list
                          WHERE login_id = 27 AND friend_id IS NOT NULL)
```

The subquery after the `NOT IN` will select the friends of the friend id you are passing. to exclude them.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e890bb/8)

This will give you only 4, 5 for the example you gave in your question:

```
| FRIEND_ID |
|-----------|
|         4 |
|         5 |
```

**Note that:** I used the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the old `JOIN` syntax you are using, it should be the same but it is recommended to use the new one.